# python memory error looping through files

Tags: python, parallel-processing, out-of-memory

I am looping through 60 files between .3 and 3gb each, performing some basic calculations, and writing out. I can't figure out why I am running out of memory at around file 48. It must be that an object or objects are getting stored somewhere and it keeps growing, but I can't figure out what it is. At the last memory error I had used 120/125 gb of ram... I am also running in parallel at two points.

Main function:

```
def write_dynamic_columns():
    perf_path = BASE_DIR + RAW_DIR
    perf_files = glob.glob(perf_path + "/*" + INPUT_FILE_TYPE)
    loanmap = BASE_DIR + APPL_DIR + LOAN_MAP_DIR + LOAN_MAP_FILE_NAME
    loanmapdata = pd.read_table(loanmap, sep='|')
    for file_ in perf_files:
        if 'time' in file_:
            print("Working on file: " + file_)
            start = timeit.default_timer()
            data = pd.read_table(file_, delimiter='|', header=None)
            final_data = pd.merge(data, loanmapdata, left_on=0,
                                  right_on='loan_id', how='left')
            final_data = final_data.iloc[:, :-1]

            with mp.Pool(processes=14) as pool:
                chunks = pool.map(make_chunks, np.array_split(final_data, 14))
                pool.close()
                pool.join()

            with mp.Pool(processes=14) as pool:
                pool.map(write_in_parallel, np.ravel(chunks))
            stop = timeit.default_timer()
            total_time = stop - start
            mins, secs = divmod(total_time, 60)
            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
            print("Finished writing quarter: " + file_ + "\n" + "ime: %d:%d:%d." % (hours, mins, secs))
```

Other functions called:

```
def make_chunks(data):
    # fill missing vlaues with missing character
    data.fillna(MISSING_DATA_CHAR, inplace=True)
    # convert mon to string
    data.iloc[:, 1] = data.iloc[:, 1].astype(str)
    # create list of months to output
    file_list = list(data.iloc[:, 1].astype('str').unique())
    # create dictionary of key=month value=dataframe
    dictinput = make_slices(file_list, data)

    return dictinput

def make_slices(files, data):
    outlist = dict()
    for mon in files:
        data_slice = np.array(data[data.iloc[:, 1] == mon])
        outlist[mon] = data_slice
    return outlist

def write_in_parallel(dictinput):
    for key, value in dictinput.items():
        data = pd.DataFrame(value)
        file_name = BASE_DIR + OUT_DIR + DYNAMIC_FILE_NAME + key + OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(file_name)
        with open(BASE_DIR + OUT_DIR + DYNAMIC_FILE_NAME + key +
                  OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE, 'a') as open_file:
            if not file_exists:
                data.to_csv(open_file, sep='|', index=False, header=HEADERS)
                open_file.close()
            else:
                data.to_csv(open_file, sep='|', index=False, header=False)
                open_file.close()
```

Comment: You realize, `multiprocessing` *copys and sends* objects across processes, right? How much memory are you working with?

Comment: 128 gigs of ram, which is why the code is designed to take 1 file, chop it into 14 pieces, process it, then write it out. Then proceed to next file

Comment: you could try to declare Pool before data loading, and reuse the same pool.